# Using Sed to extract substring from text with large text file

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I have some large semi-colon delimited text files (firewall logs) from which I need to extract from info. I've been looking at using sed (new to me), but I've been going around in circles and I can't get this working.

Each line in the text file looks similar to :

```
96;3Nov2015;23:59:00;10.22.20.13;log;accept;;eth0.500;inbound;VPN-1 & FireWall-1;;CN=FW1-FW1,O=BBB-FWMAN-01..gh;Network;353;{B2C0E4-0EFB-48AF-A1E-6B7A2543EB};Outbound DNS;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;172.1.1.4;8.8.8.8;udp;domain-udp;58364;Internal;External;domain-udp;;;;143.4.63.101;;250;1;;;******;******;;******;******;******;******;******;******;;;;;;;;;;******;;******;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;******;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;******;;******;******;;;******;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;******;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

I need to extract the '172.1.1.4;8.8.8.8;udp;domain-udp;58364' portion of the text on each line. (from 33rd semi-colon to 37th semi-colon)

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Stuart

btw, I'm doing this on a Macbook with OSX

Answer (score 2):

If there's no escaping and quoting involved, you can use just `cut`:

```
cut -d';' -f34-38 file
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I ended up using :

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{print $12,$14,$34,$35,$36,$37,$45,$46}'